# I need to split this data into its own sets so that i may call on them when need

Tags: java

in java code
 The main this I have to do is read this file into an internal data structure

I just don't know how to split each room up and keep its data together while being able to call on either the id or description  etc. by its self when need but still keeping it as all in the room, so bedroom keeps all its information but when need I can call id or description separably

(this is my data they are rooms with a ID , name , summary about it and its exit ways)

```
Rooms:
ID=1, name = Bed Room
Description :
You are standing in the middle of a dark room. It's your room, but something feels off everything is gone just a plan dark room.
You see a red light sighing under the door it seems like a way to exit. 
You can go North from here out the Door.
exits
North 2;
ID=2, name = Hallway
Description :
You enter the Hallway still noticing a red light, but it's still coming way down at the other end. You look around and notice patches of torn spots on the wall 
full of black voids looking spots. Slowly sucking in more of the room. Everything else is black, and grey, just like your room was with more objects missing.
You know the red light is at the other end of the hallway with a entrance to the living room
exits
North 3, South 1;
ID=3, name = Living-room
Description :
You enter the living room its still has some color left, but you notice its slowly fading away on the table in the middle of the room surrounded by to gray couches.
you look over to your East and hear a Scream coming from the Dinning-room
but also notice Movement through the West Leading to the Basement
exits
East 4, West 5, South 2;
ID=4, name = Dinning-room
Description :
You have entered the Dinning-room and Notice shadows moving around the room you feel a cold and lifeless wind.
You are continuing to hear Screams but not from this room its coming from the East that leads to the Front-yard The screams get louder for ever step you get closer
exits
West 3, East 6;
ID=5, name = Basement
Description :
You have enter the Basement its empty and cold never felt temperatures this low. you notice smoke coming out of you mouth but also three different spots in
each corner of the basement also forming smoke just as you are.
There is not Exit other then East where you came from.
exits
East 3;
ID=6, name = Front-yard
Description :
You entered the Front-yard you notices Shadows moving along the lawn back in the fort but no ones there just you and you garden and your thoughts the driveway has no Cars
You notice you're all alone, but it can be possible you hear and see unexceptionable things. The house is floating in a endless void there is no where to go.
your only way is back into the house West
exits
West 4;
```

Comment: This is a terrible data format: unnecessarily hard to parse.  If this is all the data, I'd start by editing it into a form that makes more sense.

Comment: You might also explain what `exits` and the compass points mean and how they are assigned.  Are they part of the description?

Comment: You should split each room using index of ID word. And then get data of each room separately.

Comment: @Gene I'd agree the data format isn't optimal, but at least it's line-oriented and has a definite structure to it. Should be easy fodder for a `BufferedReader` and some string operations, plus maybe a regex for the ID line if you want to get creative...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data, in order to determine an appropriate implementation, I feel that the the *exit* directions should be an `enum`.

```java
public enum Direction {
    EAST, NORTH, SOUTH, WEST;
}
```

And an *exit* is a combination of a direction plus a number, i.e. how many room exits are there in the given direction. So I created a `RoomExit` class.

```java
public class RoomExit {
    private Direction  direction;
    private int  count;

    public RoomExit(Direction direction, int count) {
        if (count < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative exits");
        }
        this.direction = direction;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Direction getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Finally, your sample data describes a series of rooms where each room has an ID, a name, a description and a number of exits. So I created a `RoomData` class.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RoomData {
    private int  id;
    private String  name;
    private String  description;
    private List<RoomExit>  exits;

    public RoomData(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        exits = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addExit(RoomExit exit) {
        return exits.add(exit);
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<RoomExit> getExits() {
        return exits;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d %s [%s] %d exits", id, name, description, exits.size());
    }
}
```

Then I created a "driver" class that reads the text file containing the rooms data (I named this file `roomdata.txt`) and creates a list of rooms.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class RoomTest {
    private static final String  COMMA = ",";
    private static final String  DESCRIPTION = "Description :";
    private static final String  EQUALS = "=";
    private static final String  EXITS = "exits";
    private static final String  ID = "ID";
    private static final String  SEMI_COLON = ";";

    private static int getRoomId(String line) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(line, "null line");
        String[] firstSplit = line.split(COMMA);
        if (firstSplit.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected line: " + line);
        }
        String[] secondSplit = firstSplit[0].split(EQUALS);
        if (secondSplit.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected line: " + line);
        }
        int roomId = Integer.parseInt(secondSplit[1].trim());
        return roomId;
    }

    private static String getRoomName(String line) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(line, "null line");
        String[] firstSplit = line.split(COMMA);
        if (firstSplit.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected line: " + line);
        }
        String[] secondSplit = firstSplit[1].split(EQUALS);
        if (secondSplit.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected line: " + line);
        }
        return secondSplit[1].trim();
    }

    private static void setRoomExits(RoomData room, String line) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(line, "null line");
        line = line.trim();
        if (line.endsWith(SEMI_COLON)) {
            line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
        }
        String[] exits = line.split(COMMA);
        for (String exit : exits) {
            exit = exit.trim();
            String[] parts = exit.split(" ");
            if (parts.length != 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected exit: " + exit);
            }
            RoomExit roomExit = new RoomExit(Direction.valueOf(parts[0].trim().toUpperCase()),
                                             Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim()));
            room.addExit(roomExit);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("roomdata.txt");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            boolean isExits = false;
            List<RoomData> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
            RoomData room = null;
            String line = br.readLine();
            StringBuilder description = null;
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.startsWith(ID)) {
                    if (room != null) {
                        isExits = false;
                        room.setDescription(description.toString());
                        rooms.add(room);
                        description = null;
                    }
                    room = new RoomData(getRoomId(line), getRoomName(line));
                }
                else if (DESCRIPTION.equals(line)) {
                    description = new StringBuilder();
                }
                else if (EXITS.equals(line)) {
                    isExits = true;
                }
                else {
                    if (isExits) {
                        setRoomExits(room, line);
                    }
                    else {
                        description.append(line);
                        description.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            if (room != null) {
                room.setDescription(description.toString());
                rooms.add(room);
            }
            System.out.printf("There are %d rooms.%n", rooms.size());
            rooms.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output when running the above "driver" program.

```
There are 6 rooms.
1 Bed Room [You are standing in the middle of a dark room. It's your room, but something feels off everything is gone just a plan dark room.
You see a red light sighing under the door it seems like a way to exit. 
You can go North from here out the Door.
] 1 exits
2 Hallway [You enter the Hallway still noticing a red light, but it's still coming way down at the other end. You look around and notice patches of torn spots on the wall 
full of black voids looking spots. Slowly sucking in more of the room. Everything else is black, and grey, just like your room was with more objects missing.
You know the red light is at the other end of the hallway with a entrance to the living room
] 2 exits
3 Living-room [You enter the living room its still has some color left, but you notice its slowly fading away on the table in the middle of the room surrounded by to gray couches.
you look over to your East and hear a Scream coming from the Dinning-room
but also notice Movement through the West Leading to the Basement
] 3 exits
4 Dinning-room [You have entered the Dinning-room and Notice shadows moving around the room you feel a cold and lifeless wind.
You are continuing to hear Screams but not from this room its coming from the East that leads to the Front-yard The screams get louder for ever step you get closer
] 2 exits
5 Basement [You have enter the Basement its empty and cold never felt temperatures this low. you notice smoke coming out of you mouth but also three different spots in
each corner of the basement also forming smoke just as you are.
There is not Exit other then East where you came from.
] 1 exits
6 Front-yard [You entered the Front-yard you notices Shadows moving along the lawn back in the fort but no ones there just you and you garden and your thoughts the driveway has no Cars
You notice you're all alone, but it can be possible you hear and see unexceptionable things. The house is floating in a endless void there is no where to go.
your only way is back into the house West
] 1 exits
```